# Regex for valid sharepoint folder name

Tags: regex

I am trying to make regular expression for Valid sharepoint folder name, which have conditions:

1. Cannot begin or end with a dot,
2. Cannot contain consecutive dots and
3. Cannot contain any of the following characters: ~ " # % & * : < > ? / \ { | }.

Wrote Regex for 1st and 3rd point:

```
[^\.]([^~ " # % & * : < > ? / \ { | }]+) [^\.]$
```

and for third `(?!.*\.\.).*)$` but they are not working properly and have to integrate them into one expression.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

What about just

```
^\w(?:\w+\.?)*\w+$
```

I made a small test [here](http://regex101.com/r/wZ0nV5)

**EDIT**

This also works

```
^\w(?:\w\.?)*\w+$
```

Comment: I don't know, there're only example. Those chars aren't in the list #3 from OP.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/^(?!^\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*[~"#%&*:<>?\/\\{|}]+).+$/
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(?!^\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*[~"#%&*:<>?/\\{|}]+).+$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [~"#%&*:<>?/\\{|}]       any character of: '~', '"', '#', '%',
    +                        '&', '*', ':', '<', '>', '?', '/', '\\',
                             '{', '|', '}' (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**In action (perl script):**

```
my $re = qr/^(?!^\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*[~"#%&*:<>?\/\\{|}]+).+$/;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say /$re/ ? "OK : $_" : "KO : $_";
}
__DATA__
.abc
abc.
a..b
abc
```

**output:**

```
KO : .abc
KO : abc.
KO : a..b
OK : abc
```